# Two QMainWindows: Screen Sharing apps shows the second window when in the foreground

Tags: windows, qt

I have an application with two top-level QMainWindows.

One window has all the controls and details for the user and renders the results onto the second main window, which is intended to be presented either on an external monitor or shared through screen sharing apps.

At least on Windows, even when only sharing a single one of the main windows (not the whole screen), various screen sharing applications show the contents of the other (not selected) main window if it is in the foreground and overlapping the shared window.

Does anybody know why this would happen and/or what I could do to ensure only the selected QMainWindow contents are picked up by the sharing application?

Qt Version: 5.14.2, built with MSVC 2017, 64-bit
Windows 10, multiple versions tested